# Standardized residuals

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, inference

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of standardizing or studentizing the residuals. In a linear model, we defined residuals as:

$e = y - \hat{y} = (I-H)y$ where H is the hat matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

and we defined standardized residuals as:

$r_i = \frac{e_i}{s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}$,  $i = 1,...,n$

where $s^2$ is the usual estimate of $\sigma^2$

However, I am not sure what's the purpose of this is. Would we use $r_i$ as an estimate of variance or would it just be a metric we use to evaluate our model? Also, I am not sure why $r_i$ is a function of $h_{ii}$ rather than the whole row $h_i$. I guess basically I am confused about what $h_{ii}$ stands for as opposed to row $h_{i}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $h_{ii}$ denotes the ith element of the main diagonal of the hat matrix; it is something called a *leverage*. It's a  measure of how influential a point is on the fit of the model. The higher the leverage is, the bigger the effect of an observation will be on the fit of the model.  Basically, we're penalizing points with higher leverage in by studentiziing the residuals; since a larger leverage means a smaller denominator, this means a larger studentized residual, all other things being equal. We studentize residuals in this manner to look for outliers and unusual observations in our data set. If an observation has a sufficiently large studentized residual, then we classify it as an outlier. These residuals follow a t distribution with n-p-1 degrees of freedom, so you can use a t-distribution as a reference distribution to identify which observations, if any, are outliers.